# Expected number of types of coupons collected after $n$ picks

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, coupon-collector

There are $k$ types of coupons. Independently of the types of previously collected coupons, each new coupon collected is of type $i$ with probability $p_i$ s.t. $\sum\limits_ {i=1}^kp_i =1$.

If $n$ coupons are collected, find the expected number of distinct types that appear in this set.  (That is, find the expected number of types of coupons that appear at least once in the set of $n$ coupons.)

Answer (score 16):

The types of the successively collected coupons are independent hence each event $A_i$ that no coupon of type $i$ was collected has probability $$\mathrm P(A_i)=(1-p_i)^n$$ The number $N$ of types of coupons collected is the number of events $A_i$ not realized hence

> $$
> \mathrm E(N)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k(1-\mathrm P(A_i))=k-\sum\limits_{i=1}^k(1-p_i)^n
> $$

*Sanity checks:*

- For $n=1$, $\mathrm E(N)=1$ (explain why).
- For $n=2$, $\mathrm E(N)=2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^kp_i^2$ (describe the event of probability $\sum\limits_{i=1}^kp_i^2$ involved).
- For every $k\geqslant2$ the function $n\mapsto\mathrm E(N)$ is increasing (explain why).
- And finally, when $n\to\infty$, $\mathrm E(N)\to k$ (explain why).

Comment: Another useful sanity check is that $E(N) \to n$ for small $n$.  Specifically if $n \max(p_i) \ll 1$  - or equivalently $n \ll k$ if $p_i \sim 1/k$ - then $E(N) = k - [ k - n \sum p_i + O((n p_i)^2) ] \to n$

Comment: @Did I am confused about this answer. Because if $A_1$ to $A_{k-1}$ are realized, then $A_k$ must be not realized. So that $p(A_k)=0$.

Comment: @Did How did you get the summation the formula of $E(N)$ directly from $P(A_i)$? As far as I understand, if $i$ is the number of distinct type of coupons collected in n coupons, then $E(N)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k} iP(N=i)$, where $P(N=i)$ is the probability that $i$ distinct type are present in n coupons.

Comment: My point is expectation can be found either from pmf or by using linearity of expectations. And you have used neither of them. Is there any other way to find expectations?